# CircleCI and Could not find goal 'go' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2

Tags: java, spring, maven, circleci

I try to run tests on multi modular spring project with leverage of CircleCI
I don't know why it's happen but when I try to run my spring boot project on CircleCI I get

```
    [INFO] Reactor Summary for sfg-pet-clinic 0.0.5-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sfg-pet-clinic ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] pet-clinic-data .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] pet-clinic-web ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.602 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-11T19:25:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'go' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2 among available goals analyze, analyze-dep-mgt, analyze-duplicate, analyze-only, analyze-report, build-classpath, collect, copy, copy-dependencies, display-ancestors, get, go-offline, help, list, list-repositories, properties, purge-local-repository, resolve, resolve-plugins, sources, tree, unpack, unpack-dependencies -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
Exited with code 1
```

but when I do tests manually, via Intellij everything is fine

this is my config.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: mvn dependency:go -DskipTests

      - run: mvn dependency:go-offline



      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: mvn integration-test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mvn dependency doesn't have a goal named 'go'. So the below line will fail.

run: mvn dependency:go -DskipTests

Please refer https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/